# Bulk replace nan in one column based on existing data from others

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, bigdata

Let's say we have the following dataframe below is just an example with tons of rows

| name | platform | year_of_release | genre | na_sales | eu_sales | jp_sales | other_sales | critic_score | user_score | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madden NFL 2004 | PS2 | NaN | Sports | 4.26 | 0.26 | 0.01 | 0.71 | 94.0 | 8.5 | E |
| Madden NFL 2004 | XB | 2003.0 | Sports | 1.02 | 0.02 | 0.00 | 0.05 | 92.0 | 8.3 | E |
| Madden NFL 2004 | GC | 2003.0 | Sports | 0.40 | 0.10 | 0.00 | 0.01 | 94.0 | 7.7 | E |
| Madden NFL 2004 | GBA | 2003.0 | Sports | 0.22 | 0.08 | 0.00 | 0.01 | 70.0 | 6.6 | E |

I need to run in loop through all rows where year_of_release isna() and initialize them with the year_of_release from the rows with the same name and where year_of_release not na

So by looking at the df above year_of release for record with id=183 should be filled with 2003.0

I'm looking for simple solution avoiding complex analogs based on groupby and lamda functions. Beceause I hasn't learned lambdas bfill and ffill yet. I'm only beginer and by this moment I have learned loc and queries level

Comment: Check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and update your post.

Comment: shaik, thank you for helping me to improve my style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop over dataframe, just [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `name` and transform `year_of_release` through applying backward/forward filling:

```
df['year_of_release'] = (df.groupby('name')['year_of_release']
                         .transform(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()))
```

---

```
     id             name platform  year_of_release  ... other_sales  critic_score  user_score  rating
0   183  Madden NFL 2004      PS2           2003.0  ...        0.71          94.0         8.5       E
1  1881  Madden NFL 2004       XB           2003.0  ...        0.05          92.0         8.3       E
2  3889  Madden NFL 2004       GC           2003.0  ...        0.01          94.0         7.7       E
3  5708  Madden NFL 2004      GBA           2003.0  ...        0.01          70.0         6.6       E
```

Comment: Dear Roman, your solution is definetly great. But using a lambda function is quite early for me. Could you please suggest for simpler solution maybe it is possible to do on loc[] or some sort of filters. But again, your solution is definitely answering my question and I marked it as a useful. Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: 1) Explain what is "Dera" ? 2) "for simplier solution" - does not necessarily means "effective", especially when you started with approach "*to run in loop through all rows*"

Comment: Roman, yes you are right I should avoid for loops. I have modeling this idea hundred times by trying just imagine how I would want that this solution look like, and nothing come in my mind. The best I could write here for  just to show my desired approach is something like: data.loc[(data['year_of_release'].isna()), 'year_of_release']['name] =  data.loc[~(data['year_of_release'].isna()) & data['year_of_release'] == 'year_of_release' , 'year_of_release']. I know this is compleetly stupid and not workable code, I just want to show my current level of knowledge and what approximately I'm looking